# JavaDoc @see Tag

Tags: javadoc

I would like to know if it is possible to use the `@see` tag to refer another class in an external maven project located in Nexus adding the name of the project

```
@see Project.package.Class
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Project"?

Comment: It can refer to anything within the current `javadoc` run or anything it can link to via the `-link` options.